# How create two columns based on existing column with conditions in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dateframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Car_ID': ['B332', 'B332', 'B332', 'C315', 'C315', 'C315', 'C315', 'C315', 'F310', 'F310'], \
                    'Date': ['2018-03-15', '2018', '2018-03-12', '2018', '2018-03-16', '2018', \
                             '2018', '2018-03-11', '2018-03-10', '2018'], \
                    'Driver': ['Alex', 'Alex', 'Alex', 'Sara', 'Sara', 'Sara', 'Sara', 'Sara', 'Franck','Franck']})
df

Out:    
    Car_ID  Date        Driver
0   B332    2018-03-15  Alex
1   B332    2018        Alex
2   B332    2018-03-12  Alex
3   C315    2018        Sara
4   C315    2018-03-16  Sara
5   C315    2018        Sara
6   C315    2018        Sara
7   C315    2018-03-11  Sara
8   F310    2018-03-10  Franck
9   F310    2018        Franck
```

Which contain some incorrect date? For this reason I want to create two new columns like this:

```
    Car_ID  Date        D_Min       D_Max       Driver
0   B332    2018-03-15  2018-03-15  2018-03-15  Alex
1   B332    2018        2018-03-12  2018-03-15  Alex
2   B332    2018-03-12  2018-03-12  2018-03-12  Alex
3   C315    2018        2018-03-16  2018        Sara
4   C315    2018-03-16  2018-03-16  2018-03-16  Sara
5   C315    2018        2018-03-11  2018-03-16  Sara
6   C315    2018        2018-03-11  2018-03-16  Sara
7   C315    2018-03-11  2018-03-11  2018-03-11  Sara
8   F310    2018-03-10  2018-03-10  2018-03-10  Franck
9   F310    2018        2018        2018-03-10  Franck
```

For `D_Min` For incorrect dates I want to take the date before which is right. If there the date before is not correct I'll take as it is, like the example `9  F310    2018        2018        2018-03-10  Franck`. 
And I want to do the same for `D_Max`. But if the date is correct the `D_Min` and `D_Max` should be the same.

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First replace years to `NaN`s by boolean mask and [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html) for back filling with [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) for forward filling, last replace `NaN`s by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
#only years are numeric
mask = df['Date'].str.isnumeric()
#alternative mask -check length of string
#mask = df['Date'].str.len() == 4
#not numeric return NaNs, so test non NaNs
#mask = pd.to_numeric(df['Date'], errors='coerce').notna()

s = df['Date'].mask(mask)

g = s.groupby(df['Driver'])
df['D_Min'] = g.bfill().fillna(df['Date'])
df['D_Max'] = g.ffill().fillna(df['Date'])

print (df)
  Car_ID        Date  Driver       D_Min       D_Max
0   B332  2018-03-15    Alex  2018-03-15  2018-03-15
1   B332        2018    Alex  2018-03-12  2018-03-15
2   B332  2018-03-12    Alex  2018-03-12  2018-03-12
3   C315        2018    Sara  2018-03-16        2018
4   C315  2018-03-16    Sara  2018-03-16  2018-03-16
5   C315        2018    Sara  2018-03-11  2018-03-16
6   C315        2018    Sara  2018-03-11  2018-03-16
7   C315  2018-03-11    Sara  2018-03-11  2018-03-11
8   F310  2018-03-10  Franck  2018-03-10  2018-03-10
9   F310        2018  Franck        2018  2018-03-10
```

**Detail**:

```
print (s)
0    2018-03-15
1           NaN
2    2018-03-12
3           NaN
4    2018-03-16
5           NaN
6           NaN
7    2018-03-11
8    2018-03-10
9           NaN
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hello, how can I do the same job, but by groupby 2 columns and not one? Thanks @jezrael

Comment: @M-M - Then change `s.groupby(df['Driver'])` to `s.groupby([df['Driver'], df['col']])`

Comment: It does not work. @jezrael
I got un error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: @M-M - Just tested in pandas `0.23.1` with sample data and `g = s.groupby([df['Car_ID'], df['Driver']])` - for me it working. Maybe forget `[]` ?

Comment: Yes, it was `[ ]` problem. Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

```
df_grpd = df.groupby('Car_ID').agg({'Date': [sorted, min, max]})
print df_grpd

                                              Date
                                            sorted   min         max
Car_ID
B332                [2018, 2018-03-12, 2018-03-15]  2018  2018-03-15
C315    [2018, 2018, 2018, 2018-03-11, 2018-03-16]  2018  2018-03-16
F310                            [2018, 2018-03-10]  2018  2018-03-10
```